# why $f(z)= \frac{(-e_1 + 2e_2)}{\sqrt 5}?$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have some confusion in Kreyszig book

My confusion is given below in red box

[image]

**My doubts** : Im not getting  how $f(z)= \frac{(-e_1 + 2e_2)}{\sqrt 5}?$

**My attempt** :$ \delta = \inf_{y \in Y}\|y-x_0\|$ . Here $y= (e_1,e_1/2,0)$ and $x_0= (1,3,0)$
from $ \delta = \inf_{y \in Y}\|y-x_0\|$  we have $\| 1-1 ,3-1/2,0-0\|$  by taking $e_1=1$

Therefore $\delta = \sqrt 5$

so $f(z)= \alpha \sqrt 5$

But here im not getting  why  $f(z)= \frac{(-e_1 + 2e_2)}{\sqrt 5}\text{?}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z = y + \alpha x_0$$ For any $z \in Z$, there is only one value of $\alpha$ such that $z - \alpha x_0 \in Y$, and $y$ is defined as $y = z - \alpha x_0$ for that value of $\alpha$. So each $z$ has its own value of $y$, and its own value of $\alpha$.

Let $z = (\xi_1, \xi_2, 0)$. $z - \alpha x_0 = (\xi_1 - \alpha, \xi_2 - 3\alpha, 0)$ and we want the value of $\alpha$ that puts this point on $Y$. That is $$\xi_2 - 3\alpha = \frac {\xi_1 - \alpha}2$$
which solves to $$\alpha = \frac {-\xi_1+2\xi_2}5$$